# How can I improve my question that was closed as "not real"?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

[One of my questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815942/how-to-make-a-local-offline-database) was closed as not real. However, I am unsure as to why.

I understand how my question could be perceived as a bit ambiguous:

> Is there any way I could do this with just HTML/JS?

However, having already researched the question, I was looking for how other people would do it. Also, I was not asking to code because I can't be bothered to do a bit of problem solving, I was looking for a way to code.

I received comments such as:

> Any implementation will probably depend on what browser(s) your users prefer to use.

I understand that I should have made this clear, but all of these comments that asked a question were quickly answered either in comments or in an edit to the post.

And other comments such as:

> You said you know how to use localStorage... so what seems to be the problem?

I am still unsure as to how I would use localStorage to create a database as localStorage, to my knowledge only takes key and value pairs. This comment was not constructive so i am unsure as to how I should have responded.

Therefore, I believe that this question should not have been closed as I researched and stated my knowledge, providing a question that was easy to answer for those who knew a solution to my problem.

Please advise me as to why it was closed and how I can get it reopened if it is possible.

Comment: That question was closed over 2 months ago, that's quite the delay. What came to bother you now of all times?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha i have been banned from asking questions, I decided its time to sort them out

Comment: we no longer use "not a real question" for just this reason - it confuses askers. It always meant "not a crisply answerable question" and covered too broad, can't understand you, you haven't even tried yet, and so on. Generally questions from people who don't even know where to start are not answerable.

Comment: 'Is there any way I could do this with just HTML/JS?' - there are only 2 possible answers to that question, yes and no. None of that would be a real answer, so your question isn't real either. 

What can you do? Ask specific, answerable question. Write, what **exactly** is the problem you are facing.

Comment: @samdy1: Reasonable. Added an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that the question was originally closed because it was **too broad**. Meaning, you asked someone "How do I build a house"? Instead of "How do I insert the nail correctly into the wall".

The question requires a complete article or tutorial to explain, "How to store data offline" isn't a good question.

Try to focus it on a specific problem you've had with storing data offline. Try something, post the attempted solution, explain what failed and how. Once you do that, feel free to ping in the [appropriate chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript), or flag the question for reopening.

---

Seems like you are now out of Q-ban! Congrats!

Remember that you are very close to the edge still! Post good constructive questions that would not get closed and would get upvoted, to get back into the safe zone!

Comment: So I answer it with what I did?

Comment: @samdy1 Not answer it, but edit in details and a clarification of what specific issue you are trying to resolve

Comment: @samdy1: Not *answer it*. *edit it*. You can still (and should) edit closed questions to improve them.

Comment: @samdy1 An edit will automatically throw the post into a queue where users vote on it to be reopened.

Comment: @Undo, wait I thought that only happens with "on hold" questions?

Comment: @Old Nope - it should happen with closed ones too.

Comment: @Undo: It only happens to question which were closed recently. AFAIk.

Comment: @Madara Really? I've seen month-closed questions in the RV queue - maybe they were from votes.

Comment: OK @MadaraUchiha I've edited it, do you think i have said the right things or is there something else that needs to me clarified? Also, do i need to submit it somewhere or flag it or just wait?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha should i flag for mod attention now?

Comment: @samdy1 No, it's automatically placed into a review queue that is checked by 10K users to re-open.  If they think it should be re-opened, they'll vote to re-open it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Ok thanks :)

Comment: @samdy1: Looks like you're in the clear! Read the edit to my answer.